Can you apply conditional formatting to a single word in a SharePoint Online List view
Is there JSON coding in Advanced mode (SharePoint Online) that will limit the field formatting to a single word and not the whole row?
The below code will make the whole row have red text, but I would like it to only make the word "example" red.
Is that possible?
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-RedText"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$LinktoRead.desc]"
}


You could try this:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if(indexOf([$LinktoRead.desc], 'example') >= 0, 'example', '')",
      "style": {
        "color": "red"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=replace([$LinktoRead.desc], 'example', '')"
    }
  ]
}

